# Tests don't pass using react-testing-library when adding Firebase persistence, but when testing manually, everything works

Tags: reactjs, firebase, testing, firebase-authentication, react-testing-library

I am testing my `SingIn` component in my React app. All tests passed until I added `firebase.auth().setPersistance()` to my submit handler. I use `jest` with `react-testing-library` for tests.

Part of test that fails:

```
typeLoginCredentials(email, 'badpassword');
act(() => {
  userEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Login/));
});
expect(await screen.findByText(/Wrong password/)).toBeInTheDocument();
```

and part of my submit handler:

```
...
try {
  let persistence = rememberAuth ? firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL : 
                                   firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION;
  await fireApp
    .auth()
    .setPersistence(persistence);
  await fireApp
     .auth()
     .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
...
```

When I test this manually in my browser, everything works fine. But tests pass only when I remove persistence part:

```
await fireApp.auth().setPersistence(persistence);
```

I even tried to change `findBy` timeout, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out it is the problem with node test environment supporting only `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE`.
Error was always thrown in my code when testing, but my catch block was badly implemented, so it failed only by not finding expected text in the DOM.